# Looking for a tutorial on using JUnit with Intellij IDEA 9.x

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I need an absolute beginners guide to using JUnit and Intellij IDEA 9.x together.  I'm running JDK 1.6.0_22 on WinXP.  I'm looking for answers to the following questions:

1. Do I need to install JUnit or is it already integrated into Intellij?  If I need to set it up how?
2. Assuming I have the interface and impl for a class I want to test, how do I set up a JUnit project?
3. Is there a way to autogen a test skeleton based on the class interface?

I've got experience with other Unit testing frameworks like, PHPUnit and Boost.Test, so I'm primarily concerned with the mechanics of getting all this set up and running in Intellij.

**Edit**

**I'm a complete newb using Intellij.**

I'm coming from a command-line background, i.e. C++ dev using vim and handwritten make files on Linux.

I've managed to compile and run some JUnit tests via command line ( downloaded JUnit 4.8.2 and used the -cp swith), but I'm having a heck of a time getting anything set up under Intellij.  I tried looking at the [online Intellij docs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/index.jsp), but haven't found those to be very useful.  I looked in Intellij's lib directory and it includes Junit-4.7.jar.

***I really need some kind of quick start guide with step by step instructions from initial project creation through successfully running the first unit test.***

Comment: Why was this closed?

Comment: Looks like a real question to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. IDEA comes with JUnit *support*, but bear in mind that you need to invoke tests on your project - and hence your project will need to have JUnit on its classpath.  Hence you don't need to "install" JUnit, but you'll need to make its JAR available to your project as you would with any other third party library (e.g. reference it as a Maven dependency or drop the JAR in `lib/`).
2. This is where the IDEA support kicks in - I'm 99% sure you don't need to do anything special.  Since using JUnit in general simply involves annotating your test methods with `@org.junit.Test`, as per [this quick tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/t2framework/wiki/JUnitQuickTutorial), IDEA does not require anything further.  For any class with this annotation on at least one of its methods, IDEA will give you the option to execute that class as a JUnit test case.  (Note: this *may* only be the case for files in a directory that's marked as "Test Sources" in the project structure, but I haven't tested this.  It's a good idea to set your project up like this anyway.)
3. Not by default as part of the JUnit support.  There exist other plugins to do this, but in my personal opinion this is not as useful as it might sound.  IDEA **does** have integrated code coverage (with the full edition), which (again IMHO) is a better way to ensure that your tests cases cover the full functionality of your class/interface.

Comment: +1 Andrzej. One can use JUnitGenerator plugin to generate test cases from class.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle:  Could you elaborate a bit on point 2.  I'm completely new to JUnit.

Comment: I've explained a little more specifically about JUnit tests in the second point, and included a link to a short tutorial.  I didn't realise you were completely new to JUnit; let me know if there's anything that's still unclear and not explained in the link.

Comment: @Peter Knego:  I tried JUnitGenerator, but it doesn't seem to do anything really useful.  It only generated tests for the set / get methods and seems to have ignored all the other public methods in the interface.

Comment: Was this JUnitGenerator or JUnitGenerator2?

Comment: @Peter Knego: It's version 1.1.7

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle:  I was able to run JUnit tests via command line, but can't get anything working via the IDE.  See the edit to my OP.

Answer (score 7):

For a class named Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static int add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }
}
```

write a JUnit test like this:

```
public class FooTest:
{
    @Test
    public void testAdd()
    {
        int expected = 5;
        int actual = Foo.add(2, 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

I create /src and /test folders in my IntelliJ project and mirror the package structure under each one.

You can have IntelliJ run all the tests in your project by right clicking on the /test folder and selecting "Run all tests".

If you edit configurations on your "all tests" task, you'll see a checkbox to ask IntelliJ to check code coverage for you.  It'll refresh the values after every test run.

Comment: Will this also work with an external build tool like ant?

Comment: You'll build and run test with either IntelliJ or Ant.  Your Ant task will use the <junit> Ant tasks.  The two are orthogonal.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a complete newb using Intellij.  I'm coming from a command-line background, i.e. C++ dev using vim and handwritten make files on Linux.  I've managed to compile and run some JUnit tests via command line, but I'm having a heck of a time getting anything set up under Intellij.  I tried looking at the online Intellij docs ( http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/index.jsp ), but haven't found those to be very useful.  I really need some kind of quick start guide with step by step instructions from initial project creation through successfully running the first test.

Comment: No worries Robert, we were all first-time users once.  We're all ignorant, just about different things.  I love IntelliJ, but I recognize the value of an experienced guide.  I don't have time now - work calls - but I'll see if I can do something later tonight.

Answer (score 4):

1. I guess you need to download junit library jar and add it to module settings of your project which you can get pressing Shift+Ctrl+Alt+S
2. In the module settings itself you need to select your test folders. Select the test folders and click on the test sources button on the top
   To create a test for a corresponding class press Shift+Ctrl+T.
3. I dont think there are any live templates you may need to create it. Press Ctrl+Alt+S and go to live templates and create one looking into other templates for examples.