# Setting up JUnit with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

Familiar with Java but unfamiliar with IntelliJ, how does one "get started" with JUnit integration?

Inspired by [Looking for a tutorial on using JUnit with Intellij IDEA 9.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183021/looking-for-a-tutorial-on-using-junit-with-intellij-idea-9-x) which didn't answer my questions and was for an older version of IntelliJ.

Comment: Has the power to mark this as duplicate. But refuses to use it.

Comment: @reversiblean what are you talking about?

Comment: Just saying this shouldn't be marked duplicate :)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Basically, you only need junit.jar on the classpath - and here's a quick way to do it:

1. Make sure you have a source folder (e.g. `test`) marked as a *Test Root*.
2. Create a test, for example like this:

   ```
   public class MyClassTest {
       @Test
       public void testSomething() {

       }
   }
   ```
3. Since you haven't configured junit.jar (yet), the `@Test` annotation will be marked as an error (red), hit f2 to navigate to it.
4. Hit alt-enter and choose *Add junit.jar to the classpath*

There, you're done! Right-click on your test and choose *Run 'MyClassTest'* to run it and see the test results.

Maven Note: Altervatively, if you're using maven, at step 4 you can instead choose the option *Add Maven Dependency...*, go to the *Search for artifact* pane, type `junit` and take whichever version (e.g. 4.8 or 4.9).

Comment: Doing this results in *Class not found: "Classname"Empty test suite.*

Answer (score 167):

1. Create and setup a "tests" folder

   - In the Project sidebar on the left, right-click your project and do New > Directory.  Name it "test" or whatever you like.
   - Right-click the folder and choose "Mark Directory As > Test Source Root".
2. Adding JUnit library

   - Right-click your project and choose "Open Module Settings" or hit F4.  (Alternatively, File > Project Structure, Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S is probably the "right" way to do this)
   - Go to the "Libraries" group, click the little green plus (look up), and choose "From Maven...".
   - Search for "junit" -- you're looking for something like "junit:junit:4.11".
   - Check whichever boxes you want (Sources, JavaDocs) then hit OK.
   - Keep hitting OK until you're back to the code.
3. Write your first unit test

   - Right-click on your test folder, "New > Java Class", call it whatever, e.g. MyFirstTest.
   - Write a JUnit test -- here's mine:

     ```
     import org.junit.Assert;
     import org.junit.Test;

     public class MyFirstTest {
         @Test
         public void firstTest() {
             Assert.assertTrue(true);
         }
     }
     ```
4. Run your tests

   - Right-click on your test folder and choose "Run 'All Tests'".  Presto, testo.
   - To run again, you can either hit the green "Play"-style button that appeared in the new section that popped on the bottom of your window, or you can hit the green "Play"-style button in the top bar.

Comment: Theres an easier way to do this, if i recall correctly? can you Just create a project, write a @Test and use the context sensitive error resolution to add junit as a project library. Alternatively just use ant-enter in the pom.xml to add a maven dependency.

Comment: Hmm, maybe.  I came up with this approach through trial and error, though; nothing suggested I could just write a test.  This approach is a little more explicit, anyway...  Also I'm not using Maven to manage my project.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Also If it's not working, or you can't find "run" you can simply restart intellij.

Comment: Thanks, works also for scala projects.

Comment: Thanks man! That worked

Answer (score 14):

I needed to enable the JUnit plugin, after I linked my project with the jar files.

To enable the JUnit plugin, go to File->Settings, type "JUnit" in the search bar, and under "Plugins," check "JUnit.

[vikingsteve's advice above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343428/1048186) will probably get the libraries linked right. Otherwise, open File->Project Structure, go to Libraries, hit the plus, and then browse to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.1\lib\
```

and add these jar files:

```
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
junit-4.11.jar 
junit.jar
```