# Play 2.4 and IntelliJ not resolving classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.4

I'm starting up my first Play 2.4 project and I'm having an issue with IntelliJ recognizing and finding the JUnit and Play test classes. Here is a screenshot of what I see

[image: Issue]

So basically, the code intelligence isn't picking up the JUnit dependency. The test appears to run fine when I run activator test.

Questions: What can I do to get code intelligence to pick these up
Do I need to mark specific directories as sources?

I have restarted intellij, and rebuilt using sbt.

Comment: OK. What's your question?

Comment: Have you restarted IntelliJ or even reloaded the project? Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that. I'll edit the question

Comment: tried `invalid caches and restart`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343428/1066240

All you need (after valid project import) is step no. 4:

> 4. Click the red `@Test` annotation, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose *Add junit.jar to the classpath*

Comment: Well that certainly worked. Do you know why play 2.4 does this with intellij and not 2.3? I've been using it with ultimate for forever now and never had an issue. You rock!

Comment: I think it might be an issue with SBT reporting duplicate dependencies with different version numbers.You probably get a warning every time full sbt build is executed in IDEA.  
While SBT by default evicts the older versions IDEA doesn't and screws up the classpath of your modules. See [IDEA bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8891).

Comment: Sorry @AlexanderB just now saw your comment. I've seen similar bugs with sbt itself at that version. Something weird is going on between Play, SBT, and IntelliJ and I hope JetBrains fixes it if possible. Else they could play the blame game all day between Typesafe and Jetbrains >.>