# Importing JUnit into Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried following the steps according to this SO post ([Setting up JUnit with IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330832/setting-up-junit-with-intellij-idea)) but I still keep getting the error:

```
Test.java:1: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.*;
```

where my code looks like:

```
import org.junit*;

public class Test {
    @Test
...
```

I downloaded Junit from Maven and I think I added it to the right directory (there's a lib folder in my project folder that contains the jar files). I also designated the Test folder under my project folder as the Test Sources Root. The files I downloaded are:

```
junit-4.13.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add JUnit library jars into the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies)? Does https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-testing-libraries.html help?

Comment: Look into using gradle/maven... it will make your life a lottttt easier

Comment: I think the module dependency thing fixed it. So just wondering; this runs fine if I run it inside IntelliJ, but if I want to compile this on the command line, how would I do that?

Comment: @VictorM for the command line builds consider using Gradle or Maven build tools.

Comment: How would it be any different than importing java utils? I'm wondering why that compiles fine in code with the command line, but something like this does not.