# Offline IntelliJ installation and junit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I've seen similar questions but my installation has no outside connectivity. I've tried the recommendations in several posts I'll link below but my issue persists. I downloaded both junit and hamcrest per installation instructions and have been trying to get my project to recognize junit.

[image: offline junit files]

First, the error I'm receiving when attempting to debug:

[image: No cached. version listing for junit]

I have added them to my project under Project Settings -> Libraries

[image: Libraries]

I have added them as modules via Project Settings -> Modules

[image: Project Settings - Modules]

I have it added via Gradle as a dependency:

[image: Gradle dependency]

What am I missing? Still very much new to IntelliJ so any and all help is welcome. Thanks!

[Setting up JUnit with IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330832/setting-up-junit-with-intellij-idea)

[Importing JUnit into Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327197/importing-junit-into-intellij)

Comment: Do not use images for text information like code, logs, and configurations.

Comment: Please share full code in GitHub or a Google Driver then I can take a look at it. Is it an Android project?

Comment: @aled The environment is accessed via RDP and does not provide a means for me to copy/paste between host and client. Figured since I'm just attempting to import a dependency that this would help illustrate what I had done and how I had done it so far.

Comment: @JackyLiu-JetBrains It's a project that's intended to use a fuzzing tools' SDK, not targeting Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who responded but ultimately I discovered that IntelliJ was trying to update Gradle even with "Toggle Offline Mode" enabled within Gradle settings.

By navigating to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and manually settings the distribution to "Local installation" it no longer attempted to download itself and behaved appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You hava a Gradle project.

For Gradle projects IntelliJ uses Gradle by default to:

- Build and run
- run tests

In IntelliJ 2023 the setting is under: Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Thus, you need to configure Gradle to use local dependencies.

The simplest way you can do that is using [File dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation files('libs/junit-4.12.jar', 'libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
}
```

or alternatively:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Notes:

- you seem to have used file dependencies for implementation, but not for test implementation
- junit depends on `hamcrest-core`. Check the pom for the correct version. [junit-4.12.pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom)

An alternative approach is to set up a local maven repository.