# How to search in Android Kotlin Compose UI test for a specific view? (ProgressBarRangeInfo/CircularProgressIndicator)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to check if a certain `Composable` (in this case, a regular `CircularProgressIndicator()`), is visible or not. I have this tree:

```
Printing with useUnmergedTree = 'false'
Node #1 at (l=0.0, t=63.0, r=1080.0, b=1857.0)px
 |-Node #2 at (l=0.0, t=63.0, r=1080.0, b=1857.0)px
   IsContainer = 'true'
    |-Node #31 at (l=488.0, t=908.0, r=593.0, b=1013.0)px
      ProgressBarRangeInfo = 'ProgressBarRangeInfo(current=0.0, range=0.0..0.0, steps=0)'
      MergeDescendants = 'true'
```

So, I want to wait until there is no more `ProgressBarRangeInfo` in the tree. How? I tried this to check if the app can find it, but it crashes:

```
app.waitUntilExactlyOneExists(hasContentDescription("ProgressBarRangeInfo"))
```

I have a lot of `CircularProgressIndicator`, I think I can manually set the `contentDescription` myself, but I am hoping there is a more general solution for this.

Is there a method in which I can find nodes by type?

Answer (score 1):

Using SemanticsMatcher work for me:

val semantic = SemanticsMatcher.keyIsDefined(SemanticsProperties.ProgressBarRangeInfo)

composeTestRule.onAllNodes(semantic, true).fetchSemanticsNodes().isNotEmpty()

Comment: Using the SemanticMatcher work, then I use the node founded to check if it displayed
        composeTestRule.onNode(SemanticsMatcher.keyIsDefined(SemanticsProperties.ProgressBarRangeInfo))
            .assertIsDisplayed()

Answer (score -3):

It appears you're trying to search for a CircularProgressIndicator in your Jetpack Compose UI test. I see that you are trying to use hasContentDescription("ProgressBarRangeInfo") which might not work as expected, because ProgressBarRangeInfo isn't a content description, it's actually a piece of debugging info. The contentDescription should be a human-readable text that you've assigned to the composable for accessibility or testing purposes. If you didn't set it, you won't be able to find it using hasContentDescription.

That said, here's how you'd generally look for a CircularProgressIndicator in your Compose UI test.

Firstly, you'll need to make your CircularProgressIndicator identifiable. One way to do this is by adding a test tag or content description to it. Here's how:

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier.testTag("myProgressBar")
    ...
)
```

Next, you need to use the right function to find this in your tests. The function you'll use is onNodeWithTag. Here's how:

```
val progressBar = onNodeWithTag("myProgressBar")
```

Now, you've got a reference to the ProgressBar in your test. You can use this to check if it's visible or not:

```
progressBar.assertExists() 
progressBar.assertDoesNotExist()
```

And finally, if you need to wait until it disappears, you can do something like this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        progressBar.assertDoesNotExist()
        break
    } catch (e: AssertionError) {
        // wait and try again
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

this is a very basic and not a recommended way of doing this. It's a good practice to use Idling Resources or ComposeTestRule.mainClock.advanceTimeBy for synchronization in tests instead of Thread.sleep.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).